# Facing Error during creating React app with npx

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I'm trying to create a react app through npx but facing an error mentioned below. I am using the following command:

```
npx create-react-app store-app
```

Creating a new `React` app in `D:\Projects\ReactProjects\store-app`.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing `react`, `react-dom`, and `react-scripts` with cra-template...

Below is the error message

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-17T10_53_18_174Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting store-app/ from D:\Projects\ReactProjects
Done.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change the location, because problem is caused by installing git in your current location

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few things you can try:

1. Make sure you're using the latest version of Node.js. You can check your version by running **node -v** in your terminal. If you need to update, you can download the latest version.
2. Clear your npm cache by running **npm cache clean --force**. This will remove any cached data that may be causing issues.
3. Try installing create-react-app globally by running **npm install -g create-react-app**. Then try running **npx create-react-app** again.
4. If the error persists, try running the command with permissions by prefixing it with sudo (e.g. **sudo npx create-react-app** on Unix-based systems).

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).